# Python str and text literals?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize

I don't understand. VSC is not displaying any errors, no errors on run either. This works:

```
import nltk.data
text = '''
  Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach
  do not mark sentence boundaries.  And sometimes sentences
  can start with non-capitalized words.  i is a good variable
  name.
  '''
sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
print('\n-----\n'.join(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip())))
```

This doesn't work:

```
import nltk.data

originalText = open("original.txt", "r")
sentenceTokenizedOriginalText = open("sentenceTokenizedOriginalText.txt", "a")

sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle')

with open("original.txt", "r") as originalText:
    for line in originalText:
        sentenceTokenizedOriginalText.write(
            '\n----\n'.join(sent_detector.tokenize(line.strip())))

sentenceTokenizedOriginalText.close
```

It writes to the file, but doesn't tokenize. My bet is that something is wrong between the string types, but I spent quite some time and I cannot make it to work. From my perspective I provide it the same thing - I checked and I cannot convert str to text literal. If I don't *strip()* it - it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It had been... a file encoding issue. With no warnings from python nor the functions processing text nor the VSC.

Bravo! /sarcasm